# Can a special character can be taken in a character variable with an alphabet?

Tags: java, arrays, data-structures

I want to take input in a character variable which is `A#`.
Is it possible to do that?

**Example:**

```
char E[]={'E','F#','G#','A','B','C#','D#'};
```

To solve this I have taken array type as string. Which is giving me problem to get it's ascii to calculate hash value and also with respect to sorting as well.

Comment: No, an index in an array of Char's can only be single characters. As an alternative you could use an array of Strings and convert them to Char's when necessary: `myString.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use `String` to store these since there are more than 1 character. A char can only have 1 character. You can use the default hashCode() implementation of String for hash value and the default compareTo() for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can write any character, include specials characters... For example 'Ñ'. But you can't write 'F#' in a char.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store two characters in one `char` variable. Remember that `'F#'` isn't a `char`, it's a `String` ! You should use String to store them. Then you can use `compareTo()` method for check if two strings are equal or not. [Check This out](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm)